# pion network library: testing sample webservices

Tags: c++, web-services, pion-net

I am using the [Pion Network Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pion/) to try to build some lighteight C++ HTTP web services.

I have succesfully built the sources, and I now want to test the sample web services that come bundled with the library.

I am running the PionWebServer executable, passing it the correct arguments to run the EchoService by running:

```
./PionWebServer WEBSERVICE EchoService
```

I then navigate to:

http://localhost:8080

and I get an 404 resource not found error. Has anyone managed to get any of the web service examples working with Pion Network?. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try

./PionWebServer /echo EchoService

Then access to http://localhost:8080/echo/foo/bar?query=baz should work.

Answer (score 0):

I' am using pion 4.0.5.

Use

```
./PionWebServer -d {defaultPionInstallDir}/pion/share/pion/plugins echo EchoService
```

-d: dir where your compiled service is located (NEEDED)

First time I did this I had only statically compiled libs (.a). But PionWebServer was looking for dynamic libs. So I recompiled the pion-project with dynamic libs.

EchoService will be available at

```
\\\host-ip:8080/echo
```